# How can I perform math operations on fields in elasticsearch while searching?

Tags: elasticsearch, math, search

Is there any way to perform in Elasticsearch math operations like one described below in SQL? If yes, what is the best way to perform such search operation?

```
select * from products where price + 50 > 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is feasible using a painless script query (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html).

Just give this a try:

```
GET /products/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "(doc['price'].value + 50) > 20",
                        "lang": "painless"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A prepared statement like behaviour can be done like this:

```
GET /products/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "(doc['price'].value + params.foo) > params.bar",
                        "lang": "painless",
                        "params" : {
                            "foo" : 50,
                            "bar" : 20
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```